# Index of element in one array to be equal to the index in other array ANDROID

Tags: java, android, arrays

Well, I am stuck on this problem, basically what I have is two arrays, for example

```
String[] cars = {"Bmw","audi","merc");
String[] models = {"x5","rs6","s63");
```

I need method, line of code or anything that will assign car to the model, also I should mention that car array is listed in `ListView`, so I would like to get toast,let's say user taps on BMW and toast pops up "x5". I know how to make toast, and `onItemClick` method, I am just stuck on that how to get car array index to be equal to the index of model array..

Arrays are equal in length.

I know that this is peace of cake for someone but I am stuck on it badly, whatever I try I get some error(crush)! :(

Comment: Any time you have parallel arrays like that, you're missing the point of Java being an **object**-oriented language. Create a class named `Car` with two fields: `make` and `model`. Have a single array of cars.

Comment: Well,I done it in my app,the thing that I wrote here is just example,just wanted fast and simple solution,to use in my OnItemClick method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they tap on "audi", simply loop through the `cars` array until you find "audi", then use that index to get the corresponding model from `models`:

```
String selectedCar = "audi";
String correspondingModel = null;
for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    if (cars[i].equals(selectedCar)) {
        correspondingModel = models[i];
        break;
    }
}

// Then do whatever you want with the correspondingModel
```